# Collection level job to update the Maven commit logs failed

Tags: maven, tfs

After upgrading to the TFS 2017 Update3, from the TFS 2017 RTM, the following error started to happen:

> Collection level job to update the Maven commit logs:
>
> "Failed to read storage account information : Failed to retrieve
>   settings required for storage account information from strongbox. Both
>   StorageAccountKeyBaseName and StorageAccountCount are needed."

Since I haven't been using Maven, I am not sure why this started to fail after the upgrade. If you have an idea how could I track down the root cause of the issue, or why it could appear, I will be glad to try it out.

**EDIT:** There is a similar question being asked already on the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58efedef-b823-4a50-afdd-3594580a788e/tfs-2017-tf53010-tfsjobagentexe-error?forum=tfsworkitemtracking), but it isn't answered as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that maven-scm-plugin supports the new functionalities of tfs2017... did you verify?

Comment: are you using "TF power tools"?

Comment: Actually I am not using Maven for the new jobs, but after the update it starts to fail, so I suspect that this plugin is a new one and comes directly with the Update 3 for TFS 2017. Also it says: "FeedJobsCount":0,"ScheduledFeedJobsCount":0,"MaxTryCount":2,"ExecutedTryCount":2..... , so it seems like a general one. For the Power Tools I have had an older version like 2013, but not any newer afterwards.

Comment: besides this error, is there something that is not working?

Comment: Several other errors, but they are pretty different, so I wanted to go one by one :) Usually I am able to figure them by myself, but not this time...

Comment: well that is THE problem with microsoft tools... you never know what they add inside the new features, and their (free) support is not always working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's an issue with the TFS.

Please refer to **Kristian Adrup**'s description about the issues and **Vladimir Khvostov MSFT**'s reply in this blog: [TFS 2018 RC2 is available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/09/25/tfs-2018-rc2-is-available/).

> '#2 
>   This error can be safely ignored. We fixed the problem in TFS 2017.3 and TFS 2018 RTW.

Based on the reply, the issue should be fixed in TFS 2017 update3, but seems it's not fixed yet.

I have submitted a new feedback [**here**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201124/after-upgrading-from-tfs-2017-rtm-to-tfs-20173-the.html) to track the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andy, I do have other issues with TFS 2017 Update 3 still, so I guess I would create separate threads here for them as well.